# R: control breaks intervals in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following sample of my data frame:

```
    A  B         C      pval
1   8  4 0.6714801 0.3138729
2   9  9 0.6373763 0.1402027
3   5  6 0.6695279 0.3426810
4  10  7 0.6338043 0.1722161
5   2  3 0.6692842 0.3301052
6   1  1 0.6728664 0.5777641
7   6  2 0.6608868 0.2637952
8   3 10 0.6721009 0.6584530
9   7  8 0.6338043 0.7839811
10  4  5 0.6728818 0.5045481
```

but there is something weird that is happening.

when i do a cut of the `pval` column, i get many levels

```
dataf$pval.d <- cut(dataf$pval, breaks=c(min(dataf$pval),0.02,0.05,Inf), 
                    labels=c("min","0.02","0.05"), right = FALSE)

> paste(levels(dataf$pval.d),table(dataf$pval.d))

    [1] "min 0"     "0.02 36"   "0.05 3342"
```

but when i want to plot using `scale_colour_gradient`, i get less number of breaks in the legend (`only one for 0.05`). even though its on the same column from the same data frame.

```
pl <-ggplot(dataf) + 
         geom_tile(aes(fill=C,A,B)) + 
         stat_contour(breaks = c(min(dataf$pval),0.02,0.05),
                      aes(x=A,y=B,z=pval,colour = ..level..)) + 
         scale_colour_gradient2(low="black",mid="black",high="green",
            name="\n P-value \n")
```

how can i make `scale_colour_gradient2` takes the breaks in the same way it did with cut? i think i just need to control the intervals of breaks inside `scale_colour_gradient2`, if this is possible?

Comment: you can pass `breaks`, `labels`, etc onto `scale_colour_gradient2` via the `...` argument which is then passed to `discrete_scale`; see `?scale_colour_gradient2`

Comment: @rawr i already tried this, but it seems that the `breaks` in `scale_colour_gradient2` works in a different way than in `cut`. The `breaks` in `cut` gave me 3 levels, but when i give the same `breaks` to  `scale_colour_gradient2` i only get one `level` in the `legend`

Comment: are you also aware that you refer to `pvalue` in your code but the column name is `pval`? and one of your labels is not a character string (0.02)?

Comment: @rawr sorry my bad when i wrote the question. but this has nothing to do with the problem. thanks anyway.

Comment: I get an error, can't generate contour data, maybe because there is such a small sample, but I am not sure. But generally with labels, you supply the `breaks`, `values`, `labels`, and `name` to get what you are looking for

Comment: @rawr i did not get what you meant? and why im getting different levels with for the same breaks??